# Redefine French bibliography string "visité le " by "page consulté le" in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, french

I tried

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  urldate = {page consultée le},
}
```

in Overleaf but I'm getting this error

> ```
> Package xkeyval Error: `urldate' undefined in families `blx@lbx'.
> ```

I'm using `polyglossia` and not `babel`. No `inputenc` nor UTF8. XeLaTeX.

OK, switched from urldate to urlseen and that fixed one issue. But once I used this:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
\thefield{urlday}\adddot\addspace%
\mkbibmonth{\thefield{urlmonth}}\adddot\addspace%
\thefield{urlyear}\isdot}
```

It stopped working.

Comment: Can you make a compilable MWE?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `urlseen` instead of `urldate`?

Comment: OK, I switched it to urlseen and it worked but once I added \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%\thefield{urlday}\adddot\addspace%\mkbibmonth{\thefield{urlmonth}}\adddot\addspace%\thefield{urlyear}\isdot} to the preameble it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct string is `urlseen` and not `urldate` as can be seen from

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
```

so you need

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{
  urlseen = {page consultée le},
}
```

For the date you probably want

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\thefield{#3}%
       \iffieldundef{#2}{}{\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}
```

together with the option `urldate=long`.